# Download all objects from a S3 bucket, including glacier restored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, amazon-glacier

I have set a number of files for restore from glacier to S3 and I want to download it all – the whole bucket.

When I browse the s3 bucket from the web console, I don’t see the glacier restored items (unless I show the version).

Is there a way to download all the bucket files to the local drive, including glacier restored ones?

**Edit:**

I ran

s3cmd sync s3://bucketname .

got only the non-glacier restored ones.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean when you say that you "don’t see the glacier restored items (unless I show the version)"? Are you saying that restored objects do not appear? That is quite strange.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That's right. I don't see it in the web console view. Here's the screenshot: https://d.pr/i/5yFbeO . As you can see everything is the standard. I don't see the glacier restored stuff and there are quite a few. Maybe another 20 more tar.gzs

Answer (score 6):

You can use below command to sync s3 bucket including the restored files:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname <local directory or .> --force-glacier-transfer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use our free tool to browse your S3/Glacier buckets and recover data:
https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx

Comment: Is this available for mac?